# Is there an official Instagram iOS API

Tags: instagram-api

does Instagram offer an iOS API to display a User's Instagram posts in my app?

Or is the only option using 3rd party wrappers?

Answer (score 1):

third party wrapper:[instagramkit](https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit)

Comment: Yeah that's what I got as well. I'm having a look at this, but getting issues running the demo, so far.